# selenium wget download file

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, java, files

I'm testing a web app with Selenium and I actually need to download a txt file during my test. But this seems impossible because a pop up appears asking to save the file. So, this blocks the progress of the test. Some have advised me to use Wget, but I don't know how to use this tool. Could you please help out for this?

Comment: Are you trying to test that you can successfully download this file from the site?  Or does the txt file have information in it you need for your tests and you just need some way to download it within them?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to download the file from the web app I'm testing with Selenium. This works manually but not with Selenium because of this problem https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/07/file-downloads-with-selenium-mission-impossible/ That's why I want to use WGet to solve my problem.

Comment: The reason I ask is that using WGet won't necessarily test that the link from your website is correct.  My preferred solution is to change the browser settings to do silent downloads and not have a dialog displayed.

Comment: Is this possible ? How can we not to have the dialog  displayed ? I'm using firefox and IE

Comment: Example for firefox: http://elementalselenium.com/tips/2-download-a-file
Unfortunately, in IE, there is no way to remove the dialog completely.

Comment: Yes I my colleague has already tried this solution, and it works perfectly !!! I've just add a firefox new profile and set the preferences to NeverAsk.saveToDisk !! Thank you very much @Sam Woods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WGet is a command-line tool used to download files. Here's [a good tutorial on how it works](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/tag/wget-tutorial/); you'll need to call out to the command line from inside your test and execute wGet, then check the file it downloaded. How you do this differs depending on your setup (Java vs C#, Windows vs Linux, et cetera).

Basically you want to execute the command `wget http:\\www.yourwebsitehere.com\file\todownload.txt -O c:\directory\tosave\file.txt` using the shell.

You could also do two commands: `cd c:\directory\tosave\file.txt` followed by `wget http:\\www.yourwebsitehere.com\file\todownload.txt`

Comment: Thank you Yamikuronue for your return. This is nice ! And sorry for the late ;)

Comment: @Kazman If I was helpful, please click the little "up" arrow next to my post :) And if that solved your problem, go ahead and click the little checkmark to accept the answer